# Trouble understanding onBlur/onFocus events in use case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a question regarding the code below. The behavior of the React component is correct but I would like to improve the structure of the component as well as understand why it's working.

**Expected behavior:**

- Input focused and click on button => submit action
- Input focused and click on background => loose focus
- Input not focused and click on button => focus on input

```js
const { Component } = React
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers, compose } = Redux
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux
const { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute, Link } = ReactRouter
const { Field, reduxForm } = ReduxForm
const formReducer = ReduxForm.reducer

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      focused: false,
      avoidBlur: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this)
    this.handleFocus = this.handleFocus.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (this.state.focused) {
      this.setState({ focused: false, avoidBlur: true })
      console.log('close and submit')
    } else {
      this.setState({ focused: true, avoidBlur: true })
      //this.textInput.focus()
      setTimeout(() => { this.textInput.focus() }, 0) // I don't understand why this works
    }
  }

  handleBlur() {
    if (!this.state.avoidBlur) {
      this.setState({ focused: false })
      console.log('onblur')
    }
  }

  handleFocus() {
    this.setState({ focused: true, avoidBlur: false })
    console.log('onfocus')
  }

  render() {
    console.log('render')
    const inputClass = (this.state.focused) ? 'input__opened' : 'input__closed'
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <input className={inputClass}
          type='text'
          ref={(input) => { this.textInput = input; }}
          onFocus={this.handleFocus}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          value={inputClass}
        />
        <div className='button' onMouseDown={this.handleClick}>
          Click Me!
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
}
.input__opened {
    background-color: white;
}
.input__closed {
    background-color: lightgray;
}
.button {
    background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-thunk/2.2.0/redux-thunk.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.5.4/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.5.4/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.3/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/3.0.4/ReactRouter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux-form/6.6.3/redux-form.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/node-uuid/1.4.8/uuid.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Questions:**

First of all I'm having troubles understanding why if I use the `setTimout()` function to delay the focus in the execution stack it works. If I call the focus function without `setTimout()` the behavior is completely different.

Using the following option:

```
this.textInput.focus()
//setTimeout(() => { this.textInput.focus() }, 0)
```

Doesn't work and the following stack of events triggers (when clicking the button without having the focus in the input field)

- `onFocus`
- `render`
- `onBlur`
- `render`

(I do not understand why this `onBlur` triggers)

Instead if we use:

```
//this.textInput.focus()
setTimeout(() => { this.textInput.focus() }, 0)
```

The call stack has the following form:

- `render`
- `onFocus`
- `render`

In the other hand, I would like to know if there's a recommended way of doing this kind of UI interactions using React.

Comment: Code should be posted **here**.  And the answer is probably that adjusting focus while handling another event that also affects focus generally doesn't work very well. Delaying focus changes with `setTimeout()` is pretty common.

Comment: I didn't know I could post the code like that. Even if it is a common practice I don't understand why without setTimeout the onBlur event is triggered.

Comment: The act of giving focus, the built-in browser behavior, generally happens *after* user-supplied event handlers have finished. Thus if you try to set focus in a "click" handler for an event that will *also* set focus, your change of focus will be un-done by the browser.